# Shortcut for saving words to a dictionary in PyCharm if it's not already exists.(I mean dictionary of words not a data structure)

Tags: pycharm

I have a small question is there any key combination to save the new word in dictionary without alt+enter (more actions tab). Something like when you use that shortcut highlighted word gets save into a dictionary. For example:
`name = input('Oýuna başlamak üçin adyňyzy ýazyň: ')`.

Is there any shortcuts to do that or is there a way to create shortcut for saving words into a dictionary? I'm foreign user of python and names I enter, some words I enter sometimes gets highlighted because it's in my own language and problem is that, everytime that happens I must save them.
I've even searched this manually in Keymap settings to but there's no such a thing like save to a dictionary.
[image]

[image]

Comment: By "dictionary", do you mean the Python data structure, or some kind of dictionary in PyCharm, for spell checking or similar purpose?

Comment: No, dictionary of words not data structure.

Comment: How do you currently add words to the dictionary without a shortcut?

Comment: I hover over the highlighted word and click more options and there I click save 'word' to a dictionary. I can provide you an image.

Comment: This highlighted words are doesn't exist in dictionary(vocabulary you can call it) because they're not in English. So I must save them manually by going more options I searched everywhere there is no information even in settings I couldn't find. Every time I do it gets boring.

Comment: But I can leave them as highlighted to that's not causing error but I don't like it that doesn't look clean.